# Creating a CKRecord in Cloudkit?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

I am very new to CloudKit and am trying to create a record to my public database recordType "UserProfile".

I think my syntax is incorrect in the last line of code because I'm getting the error "cannot invoke 'saveRecord' with an argument list of type (CKRecord, (CKRecord!, NSError) -> Void)'

Am I getting an error due to a Swift update that I am unaware of, any help is appreciated!

```
var nameRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "UserProfile")
    nameRecord.setValue("Jimmy", forKey: "Name")
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(nameRecord) { (savedRecord: CKRecord!, error: NSError) -> Void in

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are passing in a closure of type `(CKRecord!,NSError)` which you should be passing in one of type (`CKRecord!,NSError!)`, or one using explicit optionals rather than implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Try:

```
var nameRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "UserProfile")
    nameRecord.setValue("Jimmy", forKey: "Name")
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(nameRecord) { (savedRecord: CKRecord?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    }
```

Comment: Ah, I worked on this for hours last night and didn't even see this answer.  Thank you algal for saving me so much time!